# authenticating ldap users with searchguard for elasticsearch

Tags: proxy, ldap, elasticsearch

I have an elastic-search setup with search-guard plug-in. My elastic-search web access is behind single sign on proxy , and i want to authenticated users coming through SSO according to their roles in ldap. how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be possible by end of may when the LDAP component will be released, see https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/wiki. sg_config.yml will then look like:

```
searchguard:
  dynamic:
    http:
      xff:
        enabled: true
        internalProxies: 192\.168\.0\.10|192\.168\.0\.11
        remoteIpHeader: "x-forwarded-for"
        proxiesHeader: "x-forwarded-by"
        trustedProxies: "proxy1|proxy2"
      authenticator:  
        type: proxy
        config:
          user_header: "x-proxy-user"
          roles_header: "x-proxy-roles"
    authcz:
      authentication_domain_proxy:
        enabled: true
        order: 0
        authentication_backend:
          type: ldap
          config:  
            host: "ldapserver:389"
            usersearch: "(uid={0})"
        authorization_backend:
          type: ldap
          config:
            host: "ldapserver:389"
            rolesearch: "(uniqueMember={0})"
            resolve_nested_roles: true
            rolebase: "ou=groups,o=TEST"
            rolename: cn
```

Pls. follow https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/search-guard